# This file does not have a program associated

Tags: unetbootin

I have used Unetbootin before many times, but not recently. Today I downloaded it, chose my ISO file and hit <kbd>OK</kbd> only to be greeted with this

> This file does not have a program assoicated with it for performing this
>   action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an
>   association in the Default Programs control panel.

I found a solution using another program, but I would prefer Unetbootin. I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: [Could be a bug](https://answers.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+question/173408).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this by installing
[Universal USB Installer](http://pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3).

I will add that I like Universal USB Installer because it extracts from the ISO using 7-zip in the foreground, so you can see the progress. Contrast this will Unetbootin which extracts using mystery program in the background, so you are not sure how long it will take.

Another possible alternative, [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie)

Answer (score 0):

UNetBootin would still work.  You would just need to go into Control Panel -> Default Programs (found here) [image]

Then, scroll to the .iso file extension, and map that to UNetBootin.

Comment: Why? UNetBootin works fine here without associating the ISO extension to it.

Comment: @Karan because svnpenn says it used to work like that before, but now it's not...this is a solution...

Comment: But was ISO associated with UNetBootin before on his PC? My point is, ISO does *not* need to be associated with it for the program to function. This looks to be a bug (see link I posted above).

Comment: @Karan sure, but is it really a bug?  Not even acknowledged by the devs...

Comment: Not proof that it isn't. IMO there's absolutely no reason *whatsoever* an app like UNetBootin should require ISOs to be associated with it. All it needs to do is open the ISO and copy the files, so if it's asking for this then it is very much a bug. (Note also that the error message doesn't ask for ISOs to be associated with UNetBootin. Apparently, *any* program will do, which is really weird.)